# Modal box confirmation before submit the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, modal-dialog

I have form where user will type his information and before he/she will submit the form, there was a confirmation that indicated whether if he/she is sure to submit the form. I have try to run my code below but I cannot see the problem why isn't working. I hope you help me. thank you

here's form

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Receiving report </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets1/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style>
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);
    body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
        font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets1/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" ></script>
</head>




<form action="http://domain/portal/reports/home_members" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form-horizontal" id="my-form">                 
 <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center"><h4>Code</h4></th>
        <th class="text-center"><h4>Model</h4></th>
        <th class="text-center"><h4>Color</h4></th>
        <th class="text-center"><h4>Qty</h4></th>
        <th class="text-center"><h4>To receive</h4></th>
        <th class="text-center"><h4>Engine Number</h4></th>
        <th class="text-center"><h4>Chassis Number</h4></th>
        <th class="text-center"><h4>Complete TBA</h4></th>
        <th class="text-center"><h4>Promo</h4></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
  <td class='text-right'><input type='text' class='input-xlarge' name='promo[]' id='promo' value=''></td>
  <input type='hidden' class='input-xlarge' name='unit_cost[]' id='unit_cost' value='58000'>
</tr><tr>
  <td class='text-right'><input type='hidden' class='input-xlarge' name='order_id[]' id='id' value='6'>6</td>               
  <td class='text-center'><input type='hidden' class='input-xlarge' name='model[]' id='model' value='Raider J'>Raider J</td>
  <td class='text-center'><input type='hidden' class='input-xlarge' name='color[]' id='color' value='BLUE'>BLUE</td>
  <td class='text-center'><input type='hidden' class='input-xlarge' name='quantity[]' id='quantity' value='1'>1</td>
  <td class='text-center'><select name='quantity_received[]' class='input-xlarge'><option value='0'>0</option><option value='1'>1</option>
  <td class='text-right'><input type='text' class='input-xlarge' name='engine_no[]' id='engine_no' value='' placeholder='Engine No'></td>
  <td class='text-right'><input type='text' class='input-xlarge' name='chassis_no[]' id='chassis_no' value='' placeholder='Chassis No'></td>
  <td class='text-right'><select name='tba[]' id='tba'>
  <option>Complete</option>
  <option>Incomplete</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  <td class='text-right'><input type='text' class='input-xlarge' name='promo[]' id='promo' value=''></td>
  <input type='hidden' class='input-xlarge' name='unit_cost[]' id='unit_cost' value='58000'>
</tr>                   
</tbody>
</table>





<!-- modal caller -->
<a href="#modal-dialog" class="modal-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-href="http://localhost.testing/modal-processing.php" data-modal-type="confirm" data-modal-title="Delete Property" data-modal-text="Are you sure you want to delete {$property.address_string}?" data-modal-confirm-url="{$base_url}residential-lettings/properties/do-delete/property/{$property.id}"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Modal Submit</a>

        <?php form_close(); ?>
    </div>

</body>

</div>
<div id="modal-dialog" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="close">×</a>
             <h3>Are you sure</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
             <p>Do you want to submit the form?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" id="btnYes" class="btn confirm">Yes</a>
          <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="btn secondary">No</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: It didn't show the modal confirmation.

Comment: See , this is PHP mixed code . Give me code that you can see in HTML using inspect element , getting ?

Comment: have you included bootstrap file and jquery file? is thr any error in console.???

Comment: Hi @CerlinBoss No error on console, also I include also the bootstrap.css, will update my file. please see

Comment: it looks like you have missed `bootstrap.js` file. Include that after `jquery` file

Comment: Darrn @CerlinBoss thank you for reminding!